# How to know what all properties are ignored by @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I need to serialize - deserialized an existing Java POJO in my code. The POJO is big + it has few parent classes in the hierarchy. The code is using spring and so Jackson internally.
I started fixing one by one issue I found by fixing getter-setter name, including @JsonIgnore etc and after considerable time I fixed it completely.

But I have to fix several such classes, so for the next class, I just added:
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` which worked but during the testing I found it ignored a property it should not ignore. The property was like

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
class MyClass {
   private String xyz;
   public String getXyzValue() {
     return this.xyz;
   }
   public void setXyz(String xyz) {
     this.xyz = xyz;
   }
}
```

So basically I had to correct the getter method here.

**Question:** Is there a way to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` but list down all ignored properties for further analysis?

Comment: Perhaps you want `@JsonAnySetter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation and register your own `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler` problem handler. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"xyz\":\"X\",\"a\":1,\"yxz\":2}";
        DeserializationProblemHandler handler = new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext ctxt, JsonParser p, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer, Object beanOrClass, String propertyName) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("Unknown property '" + propertyName + "' for " + beanOrClass.getClass());
                return true;
            }
        };
        JsonMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addHandler(handler)
                .build();

        mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Unknown property 'a' for class com.example.MyClass
Unknown property 'yxz' for class com.example.MyClass
```

### Note

[JsonMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/json/JsonMapper.html) class is introduced in version `2.10`. Below this version you can use `ObjectMapper` constructor.

Comment: JsonMapper seems added in a newer release of jackson. I am on jackson-databind 2.9.8, and did not have JsonMapper. If you are on same situation, simply use
```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addHandler(handler);
```